# DRF not supporting multiple renderer_classes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-drf-renderer

I'm using **Django 2.x** and **DRF**

I have a view which returns the binary data in different formats like `pdf`, `eps`, etc.

To return binary response, I have set the `renderer_classes` property and my view is

```
class DownloadQRCode(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (PdfFileRenderer, EPSRenderer,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        name = serializer.validated_data.get('name')
        data = serializer.validated_data.get('data')

        mimetype = None

        if data and name:

            imgarr = name.rsplit('.', 1)

            if len(imgarr) == 2:
                name, format = imgarr

                if format == 'pdf':
                    data = str(unquote(data, encoding='utf-8'))
                    data, mimetype = generate_data_cairo(data, format)
                if format == 'eps':
                    data = str(unquote(data, encoding='utf-8'))
                    data, mimetype = svg_2_eps(data)

                if data and mimetype:

                    response = Response(data=data, content_type=mimetype)

                    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % "-".join(name.split())

                    return response
                else:
                    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data='Either data or mime type was missing')
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data='filename does not contain formatInfo')
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have two `renderer_classes`

**PdfFileRenderer**

```
class PdfFileRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    format = None
    charset = None
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data
```

and **EPSRenderer**

```
class EPSRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'image/eps'
    format = None
    charset = 'utf-8'
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data
```

Using any one of them is working fine for that file type. But I want to use both so that appropriate renderer can be used depending on the file requested.

But, this is giving error and only first in the set is working.

Comment: Could you please share your error (traceback)?
It should definitely be possible see: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#ordering-of-renderer-classes

Comment: What in the docs leads you to believe that you can vary the renderer by setting the content_type in the response?

Comment: Renderer class is chosen based on request's `Accept` header via content negotiation. Send appropriate header from client side to select correct renderer class. You can read more about it [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Nafees

Got it resolved by overriding `get_renderer()` method.

```
def get_renderer(self):

    imgarr = name.rsplit('.', 1)
    name, format = imgarr

    if format == 'pdf':
       return [BinaryRenderer()]
    if format == 'eps':
       return [EPSRenderer()]

    return super().get_renderer()
```